# Why don't all pages of content show up in the pagination beneath main content?

Tags: 7, views, paging

On a Drupal 7 site, I have several pages' worth of content, articles that are set to "published" and "promoted to front page". The page numbers underneath the main content part of the block show pages 1 through 5, and the "next >" and "last >>" links. However they do not show pages 6 and beyond. Why not?

I can go to the content that's on pages 6 and beyond, by going directly to the node. I can even enter the URL manually for page 6 and it loads fine, so the articles are there, published, and promoted. However, the pagination does not show links for pages beyond 5. Clicking on the "last >>" link only goes to page 5. In the image below, you can see that I've manually opened the URL for page 6, which loads the content, yet the pagination only shows it on page 5 of 5.

Is there a setting somewhere to choose how many pages Drupal shows? Or is there some other issue?

[image: Manually going to page 6 works, although the pagination still only shows 5 pages.]

Note: I'm using the default Drupal front page. I haven't configured a different view. Should this be necessary?

Comment: Is the view configured to only show 5 instead of 9?

Comment: I'm using the default Drupal front page. I haven't configured a different view. Should this be necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Drupal 7 or in some configuration. After migrating the site to Drupal 8, the full pages display correctly.